# How to prove half of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra using "degree mod 2"

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I'm encountered with the question: how to prove that every odd-degree complex polynomial has a root in $\mathbb{C}$, using the concept of "degree mod 2" from a topological viewpoint?

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: see Guillemin Pollack , page 81

Comment: I don't have that book... Could you provide a link or a brief explanation?

Comment: I can sketch the outline, you can try to fiil the details...is that ok with you?

Comment: That would be helpful! Thanks

Comment: you can get the ebook version in the internet...I am too lazy to write the whole solution...try to search it on the internet, if you can't then I'll write it down

Comment: I found it. Thanks! But I'm wondering what does the notation $\frac{p}{|p|}$ mean there?